# Как поставить Watermark на *.SWF?

Tags: xml, веб-программирование, flash, swf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно поставить ватермарк на SWF?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-й способ, Flash CS Pro (любая версия):
 - загружаем исходный SWF в новый проект, выкладываем на сцену
 - поверх кладем свой watermark 
 - публикуем проект в новый SWF с watermark

2-й способ, программный (Flash CS, Flash Develop, Flash Builder)
 - грузим Loader-oм исходный SWF и watermark (SWF, PNG, GIF, JPG)
 - добавляем сначала исходный SWF на stage (addChild()), потом watermark, ставим alpha если нужно

Помните, что любой SWF легко декомпилируется и разбирается на части, поэтому на порядок надежнее ставить ватермарк на исходную картинку.

Если это анимация или программный SWF, тут все сложнее, указанные способы самые простые. Нужно искать так называемые обфускаторы кода.

Еще есть способ загрузки предварительного зашифрованного SWF, с последующей дешифровкой в коде (ByteArray).

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно попробую. Интересно, а с помощью Swix можно как то watermark сделать?

Comment: Судя по описанию, можно. Не сталкивался.

Comment: Привет.
Нужна помощь. Не знаешь, кто занимается флеш анимацией? Не бесплатно конечно.
Есть два флеша, в каждом есть своей функционал. Их надо соединить вместе.